# Let's get critical: Dec 2013 Site Self-Evaluation

Tags: discussion, site-evaluation

We all love [Software Quality Assurance & Testing Stack Exchange](http://sqa.stackexchange.com), but there is a whole world of people out there who need answers to their questions and don't even know that this site exists. When they arrive from Google, what will their first impression be? Let's try to look at this site through the eyes of someone who's never seen it before, and see how we stack up against the rest of the 'Net.

The [Site Self-Evaluation review queue](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/review/site-eval) is open and populated with 10 questions that were asked and answered in the last quarter. 
Run a few Google searches to see how easy they are to find and compare the answers we have with the information available on other sites.

Rating the questions is only a part of the puzzle, though. Do you see a pattern of questions that should have been closed but are not? Questions or answers that could use an edit? Anything that's going really well? **Post an answer below to share your thoughts** and discuss these questions and the site's health with your fellow users!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Final Results

- [Introducing Scrum in a distributed team](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/7077/introducing-scrum-in-a-distributed-team)

**Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [jenkins build when a change is pushed to another repository](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/7087/jenkins-build-when-a-change-is-pushed-to-another-repository)

**Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [Automated White box/backend testing for a Test Engineer?](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/7095/automated-white-box-backend-testing-for-a-test-engineer)

**Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [(QTP/UFT) How do I use a test's input action parameters to parameterize a test?](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/7117/qtp-uft-how-do-i-use-a-tests-input-action-parameters-to-parameterize-a-test)

**Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Take screen shots using selenium webdriver](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/7147/take-screen-shots-using-selenium-webdriver)

**Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [How to build a test for iterative HTTP requests using JMeter?](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/7073/how-to-build-a-test-for-iterative-http-requests-using-jmeter)

**Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [How are dependencies dealt with when writing tests?](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/7140/how-are-dependencies-dealt-with-when-writing-tests)

**Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [How can I use the API that Chrome uses to check for the current version](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/7197/how-can-i-use-the-api-that-chrome-uses-to-check-for-the-current-version)

**Net Score: -1** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [How to simulate a network loss issue while Testing?](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/7128/how-to-simulate-a-network-loss-issue-while-testing)

**Net Score: -1** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [Running Selenium Script in Chrome browser in android devices](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/7211/running-selenium-script-in-chrome-browser-in-android-devices)

**Net Score: -2** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 2)

---